# QTreeWidgetItem ChildIndicator strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidgetitem

I have develop an app using a QTreeWidget and based on QTreeWidgetItem. The app is a file browser-like. Each time I had to display a folder, I create it like this :

```
    item->setText(0, foldername);
    item->setText(1,"--");
    item->setText(2,"--");
    item->setIcon(0,QIcon(":/Images/folder_pic.png"));
    item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    item->setChildIndicatorPolicy(QTreeWidgetItem::ShowIndicator);
```

and I got this :

[image]

and when expand this

[image]

This working fine but when I delete the folder "NewFolder", I lose the indicator of the parent folder even if the indicator for this parent has been set to always show the indicator

[image]

The delete code is just

delete Item;

where Item is the selected item, in my case the child of the folder apps.
I have try to remove the delete and replace it by something like

```
ItParent = myItem->parent();
myItem->parent()->removeChild(myItem);
if(ItParent != NULL)
   ItParent->setChildIndicatorPolicy(QTreeWidgetItem::ShowIndicator);
```

it's not working as well

Any idea ?

Comment: Seems that the indicator is showed only for these items that have subitems

Comment: @edwrodrig yes that"s the issue QTreeWidgetItem:: ShowIndicator is supposed to display all the time the indicator. there is another argument which is only displaying when subitems

Comment: It's a Qt bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28312

Comment: Update: I seem to have come across this buggy behavior even in Qt 6.6.0. According to the webpage of the URL @EdwinRodríguez provided, as of today, resolution is "Unresolved".